# How to avoid tick overlap with legend in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot and my plot ticks overlap with my legend as follows
[image]

and I need to move legend below the ticks.
and my code is ,

```
var plot3 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [], {
animate: true,
animateReplot: true,
axes:{
    xaxis:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions:{
            formatString:'%b',
            angle: -90
                },
        tickInterval:'1 month'
    },
    yaxis:{
          label:'',
          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
          tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
          tickOptions: {
              angle: 15
          },

        }
},
legend:{ 
    show:true,
        renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
        location: 's' ,
        placement : "outside",
        rendererOptions: {
            numberRows: 1
        }
     },
series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}],
dataRenderer: sineRenderer
});
```

is there a way to do that ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `marginTop` property for the legend renderer, as described in the [documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Legend.marginTop)

```
legend: {
     marginTop: "50px"
}
```

to specify an offset.

Here is an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/9uBgP/embedded/result/), based on the code in your question. As you can see in the screenshot the legend gets placed below the axis labels.

[image: Fiddle Screenshot]

<sub>Here is the link to the editable version of the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/9uBgP/)</sub>

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. But as I saw in their documentation the xoffset yoffset properties are deprecated. So they recommend to use marginTop , marginBottom , marginRight , marginLeft properties. I tried those and they didn't work. Can you please tell me how can I use those to move my legend box down.

Comment: @DilanG Hey, thanks for the info. I updated the Answer and the fiddle. You have to specify it like a CSS parameter e.g. `marginTop: "50px"`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it's ok the problem with my one is I didn't use " px" for margin top. Thanks again to help me.

Comment: @DilanG You're welcome :) 
Yeah, i just guessed about it. jqPlots documentation unfortunately is not that helpful sometimes